# Using `gets` for file path

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a script to edit an excel file. I'm testing if it collects information from a user.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'win32ole'

print "filpath?"
$filepath = $stdin.gets

print "sheet?"
$sheetname = $stdin.gets

excel = WIN32OLE.new('Excel.Application')
excel.visible = true
workbook = excel.workbooks.Open($filepath)
worksheet = workbook.Worksheets($sheetname)
worksheet.Cells(2,2).Value = 10
workbook.saved = true 
workbook.Save
excel.ActiveWorkbook.Close(0)
excel.Quit()
```

When I put my file path in the script directly, it works fine. It can look up the excel file and edit it normally. However, when I collect it from a `gets` statement, it gives me this error message:

```
test.rb:20:in `method_missing': (in OLE method `Open': ) (WIN32OLERuntimeError)
    OLE error code:800A03EC in Microsoft Excel
      Sorry, we couldn't find C:\filename.xlsx
. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?
    HRESULT error code:0x80020009
      Exception occurred.
        from test.rb:20:in `<main>'
```

Not sure what is happening. I would love any help.

Comment: `$filepath` is a global variable here, that's what `$` means as a prefix, and is probably not what you want. Just use regular variables unless you have a very good reason. PHP and Perl use the `$` as a matter of habit, but that can get you into trouble in Ruby.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The end line character is appended to the file name when you receive it with `gets`, but probably your file is not named as such. Add `.chomp` after `gets`. It is also better to check the existence and the accessibility of the file before passing it to win32ole.

Comment: If you're ever curious why things aren't what you expect them to be, add a simple `puts x.inspect` where `x` is the variable you're confused about. This would show up as `"C:\\filename.xlsx\n"` and the additional character would be more obvious.

Comment: @tadman Why recommend `puts x.inspect`? `p x` is better, and will have less trouble since it returns the receiver.

Comment: That's also a useful approach, but don't forget there are some places where `puts` is ineffective, so knowing about what `.inspect` does is still useful. E.g. `raise x.inspect` or `<%= x.inspect %>`